# Unable to match a space or a dollar amount as part of a named capture

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to match a space or a dollar amount between the words `"red"` and `"blue"`. I'm using a pattern that matches a dollar amount but not the space.

```
"red$1,000.00blue".match /red(<end_val> |(\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d{2}))blue/
# => #<MatchData "red$1,000.00blue" 1:"$1,000.00" 2:"$1,000.00" 3:",000">

"red blue".match /red(<end_val> |(\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d{2}))blue/
# => nil
```

What is wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: What is that `<end_val>` part?

Comment: Aha!  It's supposed to be a named capture (it's part of a larger regex).  I see from the docs that named captures need a preceding question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed a question mark before `<end_val>` for it to work as a [named capture](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-named_captures).  Without the preceding question mark it was treated as part of the regular expression.

```
"red blue".match /red(?<end_val> |(\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d{2}))blue/
# => #<MatchData "red blue" end_val:" ">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<end_val>` from your pattern:

```
"red blue".match /red( |(\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d{2}))blue/
#=> #<MatchData "red blue" 1:" " 2:nil 3:nil>
```

… or use the correct syntax for named captures from Steven Rumbalski’s answer.